# Pandas plot multiple category lines

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Say I have the following data...

```
date      Score  category                 
2017-01-01   50.0         1
2017-01-01  590.0         2
2017-01-02   30.0         1
2017-01-02  210.4         2
2017-01-03   11.0         1
2017-01-03   50.3         2
```

So on a daily basis, I have multiple categories, each being assigned a score. 
Here's my code so far...

```
vals = [{'date': '2017-01-01', 'category': 1, 'Score': 50},
         {'date': '2017-01-01', 'category': 2, 'Score': 590},
         {'date': '2017-01-02', 'category': 1, 'Score': 30},
         {'date': '2017-01-02', 'category': 2, 'Score': 210.4},
         {'date': '2017-01-03', 'category': 1, 'Score': 11},
         {'date': '2017-01-03', 'category': 2, 'Score': 50.3}]
df = pd.DataFrame(vals)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.set_index(['date'],inplace=True)
```

Which results in a bizarre plot as below.
[image]

I'd like to have multiple lines, one for each category, and the date on the X-axis - how would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use groupby and plot

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for label, grp in df.groupby('category'):
    grp.plot(x = grp.index, y = 'Score',ax = ax, label = label)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Let's try using axes with `ax=ax` and parameter `secondary_y=True`:

```
ax = df.plot(x=df.index, y='Score')
df.plot(x=df.index, y='category', secondary_y=True, ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]

Or if @Vaishali plot is what you want you can do it with this one-liner.

```
df.set_index('category',append=True).unstack()['Score'].plot()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You do love set_index(), stack, unstack!:)

Comment: @Vaishali.  Thank you!