# Splitting graphs into different categories from one dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

How can I use 4 different charts to show the different revenue for the 4 different regions (Midwest, Northeast, South, west)?

I used df.plot() but it is only showing one line with all revenue included from all 4 regions.

```
            Region  Revenue
Date        
2018-12-31  Midwest     652.0
2018-12-31  South       9465.3
2018-12-31  West        329.5
2018-12-31  Northeast   94063.0
2019-01-07  Midwest     2793.0
2019-01-07  South       20220.00
2019-01-07  Northeast   2544.75
2019-01-07  West        22342.35
2019-01-14  South       23434.75
2019-01-14  Midwest     23429.50
2019-01-14  West        2292.15
2019-01-14  Northeast   24520.50
2019-01-21  West        2477.00
2019-01-21  South       22355.25
2019-01-21  Midwest     28666.00
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas plot multiple category lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717359/pandas-plot-multiple-category-lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) first and then `subplots=True`

```
df.pivot(columns=['Region']).plot(subplots=True)
```

Output:

[image]